# Opera throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null when a <object> of type SVG is present

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I am testing some code and the Opera (53.0) console is giving me this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at FilterContent.initialize_ (filter_content.js:148)
at whenDomReady_.then (filter_content.js:21)
```

It is thrown once for every `<object type="image/svg+xml">` that I have on my page. E.g.

```
<object class="inputClass" id="surfaceDiag" type="image/svg+xml" data="LookDiagram.svg"></object>
```

I reduced the number of `<object>` in order to be sure of the causality and commented all my own Javascript calls to be sure it is not caused by my own code.

I am not calling the function that throws the error.
Testing the same code in Firefox does not give any errors.
Is (still) something wrong with the code or is it simply a Opera bug?

Comment: What is there in filter_content.js at line number 148?

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by the builtin adblocker of Opera. I have this error too, and I've found out that, when disabling the builtin adblocker on my page, the error is gone.

Maybe the error is also caused by other adblockers.

Comment: Thanks, Marvin.
There was a TypeError in contentFilterPrivate.isURLBlocked.